# Triangle with Center of mass at O where O is in convex polygon

Tags: geometry, discrete-geometry

Prove or disprove: for every convex polygon Q containing O in its relative interior,  there exists a triangle inscribed in Q with center of mass at O.

Im stuck at this problem. Need help please

Comment: If it were a segment instead of a triangle: Draw a line across $O$ and take the segment formed by the points where it intersects with the polygon. $O$ might be at one side of the midpoint of the segment. As you rotate the line two right angles $O$ changes from one side of the midpoint of the segment to the other. Therefore, at some angle it coincided with the mid point.

Comment: For the case of a triangle, consider the set of all centers of gravity of triangles inscribed in $Q$. By using points on $Q$ very close together you can enclose $O$ in a loop formed by their centers of gravity. Now assume that $P_1,P_2$ are centers of gravity of two inscribed triangles. Show that any point $P$ in the segment $P_1P_2$ is the center of gravity of some inscribed triangle.